# C# Resizing the windows desktop and adding a bar in the space

Tags: c#

Here is an example of what I am trying to do except I don't want to be covering my recycle bin and I don't want windows covering the bar.

[image: Example Panel]

I'm writing a panel that is located on the top of the screen. The panel should be always visible and should not cover title bars of maximized windows - just like taskbar with start menu when it's located on the top.

I am getting the error "SystemParametersInfo does not exist in this context"

Also SPI_GETWORKAREA and SPIF_SENDCHANGE are both commented out. I am not sure what to do in this area.

Maybe I dont have the struct in the correct place? I may not be putting the code in the right area. If someone could show me a complete example using this code I would appreciate it. Thank you!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[Flags]
public enum SPIF
{
    None = 0x00,
    /// <summary>Writes the new system-wide parameter setting to the user profile.</summary>
    SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x01,
    /// <summary>Broadcasts the WM_SETTINGCHANGE message after updating the user profile.</summary>
    SPIF_SENDCHANGE = 0x02,
    /// <summary>Same as SPIF_SENDCHANGE.</summary>
    SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE = 0x02
}

#region SPI
    /// <summary>
    /// SPI_ System-wide parameter - Used in SystemParametersInfo function
    /// </summary>
        [Description("SPI_(System-wide parameter - Used in SystemParametersInfo function )")]
        public enum SPI : uint
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Retrieves the size of the work area on the primary display monitor. The work area is the portion of the screen not obscured
            /// by the system taskbar or by application desktop toolbars. The pvParam parameter must point to a RECT structure that receives
            /// the coordinates of the work area, expressed in virtual screen coordinates.
            /// To get the work area of a monitor other than the primary display monitor, call the GetMonitorInfo function.
            /// </summary>
            SPI_GETWORKAREA = 0x0030
        }
#endregion

namespace test
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public const uint SPI_SETWORKAREA = 0x002F;
        public const uint SPI_GETWORKAREA = 0x0030;
        public const uint SPIF_SENDCHANGE = 0x02;

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        //                                 SPI_GETWORKAREA 0x0030, 0  ,pvParam points to Rec, send global change
        static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(SPI uiAction, uint uiParam, ref Rect pvParam, SPIF fWinIni);
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public struct Rect
        {
            public Int32 Left, Top, Right, Bottom;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Rect DeskArea = new Rect();
            SystemParametersInfo(48/*SPI_GETWORKAREA*/, 0, ref DeskArea, 2/*SPIF_SENDCHANGE*/);
            this.Left = 0;
            this.Width = DeskArea.Right;
            this.Top = DeskArea.Bottom - this.Height - 4;
            DeskArea.Bottom = DeskArea.Bottom - 150;
            SystemParametersInfo(47/*SPI_SETWORKAREA*/, 0, ref DeskArea, 2/*SPIF_SENDCHANGE*/);
        }

        //And now you need to replace the orkarea to its original size.

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Rect DeskArea = new Rect();
            SystemParametersInfo(48/*SPI_GETWORKAREA*/, 0, ref DeskArea, 2/*SPIF_SENDCHANGE*/);
            DeskArea.Bottom = DeskArea.Bottom + 150;
            SystemParametersInfo(47/*SPI_SETWORKAREA*/, 0, ref DeskArea, 2/*SPIF_SENDCHANGE*/);
        }
    }
}
```

I've made some edits but still have no luck when trying to use systemParametersInfo I have tried Integer values and the hex values

Comment: How is SystemParametersInfo declared/externed your code?

Comment: Its not, that's what I need help with. This is all of the code I have. I don't know where the API would go. The parameters(int, int, ref, int) I guess?

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Sample.AppBar
{
/// <span class="code-SummaryComment"><summary></span>
/// Summary description for Form1.
/// <span class="code-SummaryComment"></summary></span>
public class MainForm : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    /// <span class="code-SummaryComment"><summary></span>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// <span class="code-SummaryComment"></summary></span>
    private System.ComponentModel.Container components = null;

    public MainForm()
    {
        //
        // Required for Windows Form Designer support
        //
        InitializeComponent();

        //
        // TODO: Add any constructor code after InitializeComponent call
        //
    }

    /// <span class="code-SummaryComment"><summary></span>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// <span class="code-SummaryComment"></summary></span>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (components != null)
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <span class="code-SummaryComment"><summary></span>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// <span class="code-SummaryComment"></summary></span>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // MainForm
        // 
        this.AutoScaleBaseSize = new System.Drawing.Size(5, 13);
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(960, 50);
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow;
        this.Name = "MainForm";
        this.Text = "AppBar";
        this.Closing += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(this.OnClosing);
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.OnLoad);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }
    #endregion

    #region APPBAR

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct RECT
    {
        public int left;
        public int top;
        public int right;
        public int bottom;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct APPBARDATA
    {
        public int cbSize;
        public IntPtr hWnd;
        public int uCallbackMessage;
        public int uEdge;
        public RECT rc;
        public IntPtr lParam;
    }

    enum ABMsg : int
    {
        ABM_NEW = 0,
        ABM_REMOVE = 1,
        ABM_QUERYPOS = 2,
        ABM_SETPOS = 3,
        ABM_GETSTATE = 4,
        ABM_GETTASKBARPOS = 5,
        ABM_ACTIVATE = 6,
        ABM_GETAUTOHIDEBAR = 7,
        ABM_SETAUTOHIDEBAR = 8,
        ABM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED = 9,
        ABM_SETSTATE = 10
    }

    enum ABNotify : int
    {
        ABN_STATECHANGE = 0,
        ABN_POSCHANGED,
        ABN_FULLSCREENAPP,
        ABN_WINDOWARRANGE
    }

    enum ABEdge : int
    {
        ABE_LEFT = 0,
        ABE_TOP,
        ABE_RIGHT,
        ABE_BOTTOM
    }

    private bool fBarRegistered = false;

    [DllImport("SHELL32", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    static extern uint SHAppBarMessage(int dwMessage, ref APPBARDATA pData);
    [DllImport("USER32")]
    static extern int GetSystemMetrics(int Index);
    [DllImport("User32.dll", ExactSpelling = true,
        CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern bool MoveWindow
        (IntPtr hWnd, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, bool repaint);
    [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern int RegisterWindowMessage(string msg);
    private int uCallBack;

    private void RegisterBar()
    {
        APPBARDATA abd = new APPBARDATA();
        abd.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(abd);
        abd.hWnd = this.Handle;
        if (!fBarRegistered)
        {
            uCallBack = RegisterWindowMessage("AppBarMessage");
            abd.uCallbackMessage = uCallBack;

            uint ret = SHAppBarMessage((int)ABMsg.ABM_NEW, ref abd);
            fBarRegistered = true;

            ABSetPos();
        }
        else
        {
            SHAppBarMessage((int)ABMsg.ABM_REMOVE, ref abd);
            fBarRegistered = false;
        }
    }

    private void ABSetPos()
    {
        APPBARDATA abd = new APPBARDATA();
        abd.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(abd);
        abd.hWnd = this.Handle;
        abd.uEdge = (int)ABEdge.ABE_TOP;

        if (abd.uEdge == (int)ABEdge.ABE_LEFT || abd.uEdge == (int)ABEdge.ABE_RIGHT)
        {
            abd.rc.top = 0;
            abd.rc.bottom = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Height;
            if (abd.uEdge == (int)ABEdge.ABE_LEFT)
            {
                abd.rc.left = 0;
                abd.rc.right = Size.Width;
            }
            else
            {
                abd.rc.right = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Width;
                abd.rc.left = abd.rc.right - Size.Width;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            abd.rc.left = 0;
            abd.rc.right = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Width;
            if (abd.uEdge == (int)ABEdge.ABE_TOP)
            {
                abd.rc.top = 0;
                abd.rc.bottom = Size.Height;
            }
            else
            {
                abd.rc.bottom = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Height;
                abd.rc.top = abd.rc.bottom - Size.Height;
            }
        }

        // Query the system for an approved size and position. 
        SHAppBarMessage((int)ABMsg.ABM_QUERYPOS, ref abd);

        // Adjust the rectangle, depending on the edge to which the 
        // appbar is anchored. 
        switch (abd.uEdge)
        {
            case (int)ABEdge.ABE_LEFT:
                abd.rc.right = abd.rc.left + Size.Width;
                break;
            case (int)ABEdge.ABE_RIGHT:
                abd.rc.left = abd.rc.right - Size.Width;
                break;
            case (int)ABEdge.ABE_TOP:
                abd.rc.bottom = abd.rc.top + Size.Height;
                break;
            case (int)ABEdge.ABE_BOTTOM:
                abd.rc.top = abd.rc.bottom - Size.Height;
                break;
        }

        // Pass the final bounding rectangle to the system. 
        SHAppBarMessage((int)ABMsg.ABM_SETPOS, ref abd);

        // Move and size the appbar so that it conforms to the 
        // bounding rectangle passed to the system. 
        MoveWindow(abd.hWnd, abd.rc.left, abd.rc.top,
            abd.rc.right - abd.rc.left, abd.rc.bottom - abd.rc.top, true);
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == uCallBack)
        {
            switch (m.WParam.ToInt32())
            {
                case (int)ABNotify.ABN_POSCHANGED:
                    ABSetPos();
                    break;
            }
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    protected override System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.Style &= (~0x00C00000); // WS_CAPTION
            cp.Style &= (~0x00800000); // WS_BORDER
            cp.ExStyle = 0x00000080 | 0x00000008; // WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | WS_EX_TOPMOST
            return cp;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    /// <span class="code-SummaryComment"><summary></span>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// <span class="code-SummaryComment"></summary></span>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }

    private void OnLoad(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterBar();
    }

    private void OnClosing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterBar();
    }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's all the code you have, SystemParametersInfo needs to be declared like so:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(SPI uiAction, uint uiParam, ref T pvParam, SPIF fWinIni);
```

<sub>[See more detailed usage instructions in PInvoke.NET](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SystemParametersInfo.html).</sub>

Comment: Okay but where would I put this at? I have tried adding this before and the bool was flagged as an error. IE. static extern BOOL

Comment: Okay i have added your version but SPI, T and SPIF "Type or namespace not found"

Comment: I think you either have to define them yourself (See "User-Defined Types:" in the link I provided) or change the declaration to uint and edit the usage accordingly.

Comment: I don't recognize these types and the MSDN site displays everything in C++

Comment: PI_GETWORKAREA
0x0030

 

Retrieves the size of the work area on the primary display monitor. The work area is the portion of the screen not obscured by the system taskbar or by application desktop toolbars. The pvParam parameter must point to a RECT structure that receives the coordinates of the work area, expressed in virtual screen coordinates.

To get the work area of a monitor other than the primary display monitor, call the GetMonitorInfo function.

Comment: As I said earlier SPI, T and SPIF are not recognized as types. Maybe I am missing and include statement?